# Optimize a query querying a large dataset

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables - buckets and services. Buckets has 3000 records and services has 300 million records. Is there a way to optimize the below query so it runs faster?

I am trying to find unique NPIs per bucket.

```
SELECT bucketname, count(*) from services sl
join buckets b 
on b.code = sl.CD
group by bucketName, sl.npi;
```

Comment: Unfortunately because you are doing a count query basically across the full result of the join, any index might be very useful.  So, I don't see much room for improvement.

Comment: @Aaron . . . I don't get it.  You are aggregating by `sl.npi` but you are not showing this value anywhere.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I want to `count` the no.of unique NPIs. Should I do `count (sl.npi)` instead of `count (*)`.

Comment: try COUNT(DISTINCT sl.npi) to get the count of unique values, but be aware that it will add additional work for the engine...

Comment: Is the combination of `code, bucketname` unique in `buckets`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the number of distinct somethings, then use `count(distinct)`:

```
select b.bucketname, count(distinct sl.npi)
from services sl join
     buckets b 
     on b.code = sl.CD
group by b.bucketName;
```

This at least returns what you want.  It is doubtful that it will improve performance.